# Binding Object with ObservableCollection<double>

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

One one side I have a generic viewModel class with a property named Value. As this class can be use in different cases, the type of Value is Object.

On the other side I have a list control with an ObservableCollection property named Items.

Is it possible to create a binding between Value and Items?

First I tried to bind them directly, but Items setter is never called

```
this.SetBinding (
   () => Data.Value,
   () => Items
);
```

Then I tried casting the Object property, Items setter is now called but the changes are never applied back to Data.Value

```
this.SetBinding (
   () => Data.Value)
.WhenSourceChanges (
   () => Items = Data.Value as ObservableCollection<double> )
```

Comment: What do you mean, on one side and other side?  Are you trying to bind the selected value of the list control?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to bind values in my viewModel to my list control

Comment: So `Value` is some sort of collection?

Comment: Value is of type Object because it’s a generic class used in different case but in this specific case, Value contains an ObservableCollection

    `public class Content {   
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public Object Value { get; set; }  
  }`